# How to use thymeleaf namespace for including a header and footer of a page without using any templateresolver?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a login page in which I have declared the inclusion of common templates as below

"head" is the fragment name for header attribute in common.html and it includes inclusion of all the common js and css files.

When I access the URL I see none of these css are being loaded on the page. To be noted here I am not using any templateresover classes or engine classes, it's purely static.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta name="loginPage" />
<meta th:remove="tag" th:include="../fragments/common :: [//head]"/>

</head>
<body  class="claro">
<div></div>
        <br />
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-1-1" style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
                <form class="form" t">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Please login</legend>
                        <div class="col-1-1">
                            <div class="label">
                                User Name:
                            </div>
                            <div class="input">
                                <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="user_name" length="35" required="true" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1-1">
                           <div class="label"> 
                                Password:
                           </div> 
                           <div class="input">
                            <input  id="password" name="password" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                                type="password" required="required" maxlength="100" />
                           </div>
                         </div>
                           <div class="col-1-1">
                                <div class="module">
                                    <input type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"
                                        id="save_msg_button" intermediateChanges="false"
                                        label="Login" iconClass="dijitNoIcon"></input>
                                </div>
                           </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
         </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the common.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->

<!-- stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/grid.css}" href=""
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app.css" href=""
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app.css" href=""
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../cdn/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/document.css"
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../cdn/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../cdn/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/Gridx.css"
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../cdn/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/Gridx_rtl.css"
    type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../cdn/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/ExpandoPane.css"
    type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Body goes here</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show some code, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to statically prototype the template with fragments.

When a Thymeleaf template is used as a static prototype, you will not see the fragments you are including using the th:include/th:replace.

In my opinion, you have two choices:

1. Create a static prototyping code, that will be removed at runtime like in this file: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-layouts/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home/homeNotSignedIn.html
2. Use Thymol - an unofficial JavaScript library that is an implementation of Thymeleaf's standard fragment inclusion functionality, providing static support for some Thymeleaf attributes like th:include or th:replace. See: http://sourceforge.net/u/jjbenson/wiki/thymol/